# Cannot Bind view variables

Tags: android, butterknife

When I try to bind, I get an error saying that cannot resolve method 'bind(name of my main activity)'.

```
@BindView(R.id.timeLabel) TextView mTimeLabel;
@BindView(R.id.temperatureLabel) TextView mTemperatureLabel;
@BindView(R.id.humidityValue) TextView mHumidityValue;
@BindView(R.id.precipValue) TextView mPrecipValue;
@BindView(R.id.summaryTextView) TextView mSummaryLabel;
@BindView(R.id.iconImageview) ImageView mIconImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Import view variables
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

Comment: Please, post more error info

Comment: Can you, please, provide your layout xml source?

Comment: @DenisGL the XML - http://pastebin.com/QcEvHttP

Comment: As ButterKnife is relying on code generation (and not on reflection), it is using an Annotation Processor. Did you add this line in your build.gradle: `apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'`?

Comment: @user2683183 Replace `BindView` to `InjectView`.

Comment: @jaydroider InjectView is no longer used according to Butterknife documentation in the new version

Answer (score -1):

Looks like there was something wrong with Android Studio. What I did was I went to  File -- invalidate Caches and restart. When Android Studio restarted everything worked fine.